# Keyboard shortcut to completely hide Java-doc comments so they take no lines in the code anymore

Tags: java, intellij-idea, android-studio

I know the shortcuts:

`CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `+`

`CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `-`

Which expand and minimize Java-doc comments respectively. However this way of line collapsing keeps a line of space:

[image]

**How do you collapse so that no lines of code are occupied by comments anymore?** How I see it is that the java-doc comments from above takes 1 line of code.

**I try to work distraction free and thus only want to show my actual code.**

---

*[Here is the official page of Intellij where their code folding shortcuts are summarised](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/code-folding.html)  (Android Studio is a fork of Intellij so they have almost the same shortcuts). I can't find the shortcut I am looking for here.*

Comment: My guess is, you can't, and most probably not directly by a default shortcut. Because then it'd be hard to spot that there is something hidden.

Comment: It could theoretically add a mark _ on the line above as a horizontal stripe to mark there is something hidden instead of needing a whole line for it. Or even better just show a toggle somewhere that they are hidden. But I understand your reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the part you want to hide and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Choose either

```
//<editor-fold desc="Description">
// part to hide
//</editor-fold>
```

or

```
//region Description
// part to hide
//endregion
```

Change `Description` to something that won't distract you, for example `_`.
After collapsing this block you will see only `_`.

Comment: The `Ctrl+Alt+...` short cuts in appications are terrible, as these are used by OS Win. :(

Answer (score 6):

Code -> Folding -> Collapse doc comments